# Stored procedure execute output error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This is my code for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.EnrollStudent ( @CourseID  AS INTEGER,
                                     @StudentID AS VARCHAR(20), 
                                     @Status AS VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT ) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @StutusID INTEGER

   IF @StutusID = 1
   BEGIN  
       SET @Status = 'The Student is already Enrolled'
   END;

   ELSE IF @StutusID = 2
   BEGIN 
       SET @Status = 'Cannot enroll until faculty is selected' 
   END

   ELSE IF @StutusID = 3
   BEGIN 
       SET @Status = 'Student Enrolled' 
   END

   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM dbo.CourseEnrollment 
                WHERE dbo.CourseEnrollment.CourseId=@CourseID AND dbo.CourseEnrollment.StudentId=@StudentID )
   BEGIN
      SET @StutusID = 1
   END


END;
```

And this is how I'm trying to execute it...

```
DECLARE @Status1 VARCHAR(50)
EXEC dbo.EnrollStudent @CourseID=1, @StudentID='01-HJPotter', @Status= @Status1 OUT;
```

And this is the error I'm getting

> Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Procedure EnrollStudent, Line 0
>   Procedure or function EnrollStudent has too many arguments specified.

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: This is weird, since this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ad90/1) shows no error

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: The fiddle also uses SQL Server 2008. I only removed a semmicolon in the first `END` and didn't use the table, but the sp works

Comment: I just restarted it, and it executed sucessfully, but didn't show the output :/  I have the matching input as it is in the tables.

Comment: Well, that's a problem with your sp logic. Look, you declare `@StutusID` and don't assign a value, so it's `NULL` at first. So, `IF @StutusID = 1` is false, `IF @StutusID = 2` is also false and `IF @StutusID = 2` is false too (they are not technically `false` but `unknown` wither way they are not `true`). Then, assuming that `IF EXISTS` is true, then at this point you also don't assign a value to `@Status`, so that variable will **always** be `NULL`

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize the order or placing the commands will make a difference. I move the commands which SET status based on STATUS ID after the EXIST command, and it works now.

Comment: Glad it works now, and of course the order matters ;-)

Answer (score 0):

why do you have a declare? Try this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.EnrollStudent ( @CourseID  AS INTEGER,
                                 @StudentID AS VARCHAR(20), 
                                 @Status AS VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT ) AS
BEGIN

IF @StutusID = 1
BEGIN  
    SET @Status = 'The Student is already Enrolled'
END;

ELSE IF @StutusID = 2
BEGIN 
   SET @Status = 'Cannot enroll until faculty is selected' 
END

ELSE IF @StutusID = 3
BEGIN 
   SET @Status = 'Student Enrolled' 
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM dbo.CourseEnrollment 
            WHERE dbo.CourseEnrollment.CourseId=@CourseID AND       dbo.CourseEnrollment.StudentId=@StudentID )
BEGIN
  SET @StutusID = 1
END


END;
```